# Angular 1.3 - how to handle timezones in date and time input fields

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

### Background Story:

My Application is timezone aware. Users can select a specific timezone and all date inputs expect values according to that timezone. E.g. if I chose the timezone New York City, every input field expects and displays UTC-5 dates.

With Angular 1.2 I managed that with [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/). Any input[date] had a string generated by moment as model. Then I upgraded to Angular 1.3.

### The Issue:

Angular 1.3 requires a native Date object as model for all date related input fields. Native date objects only support the browsers timezone or UTC.

**So how to manage timezones with Angular 1.3?** Can I remove the validator from the modelController somehow? Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: this library may help you. It allows to change the locale at runtime, so it should allow you to manipulate the timezone with the locale https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale

Comment: @sam: are you sure locale will effect timezone? Afaik. you cannot change the browsers timezone at runtime

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way that is not very clean and could have side effects.

I am using a directive to remove validators on specific input fields:

```
OMD.app.directive('clearValidators', function ($window) {
    return {
        require:'^ngModel',
        restrict:'A',
        link:function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$formatters = [];
            ctrl.$parsers = [];
        }
    };
});
```

This is how to apply it to the input. It seems like it adds the required validator after I cleared the default validators.

```
<input clear-validators type="datetime-local" ng-model="zoneTime" ng-required="required"/>
```

It works as with Angular 1.2 I don't like this approach though.